# AngularJS Disable unchecked checkbox in ng-repeat with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of vochers that are shown with ng-repeat from a WebService, and each vocher has an associated checkbox, when I check a specific checkbox the price of the vocher is deduct of the Total Price, the problem in question is: " once the Total price is 0 I have to disable the unchecked checkbox" at the moment I can disable them all but I want to keep the checked checkboxes enable so I can uncheck them again.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="slide in MesAvoirs | limitTo: slideLength track by $index">
    <div class="mes_avoires" ng-repeat="a in MesAvoirs  | startFrom: ($index*5) | limitTo: 5">
        <input class="mes_avoires_checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="check" ng-change="avoirPrixCal($index,check,a)" id="chBx-{{$index}}" ng-disabled="uncheckVar" />
        <div class="left_av">
            <em>{{"MonProfilMesAvoirs.Num_Avoir" | translate}} {{a.NumeroAvoir}}</em>
            <strong>{{a.Montant}} {{"Globale.Devise" | translate}}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="right_av">
            <em translate="MonProfilMesAvoirs.Valide_till"></em>
            <strong>{{a.DateValiditeJ }} {{a.DateValiditeM}} {{a.DateValiditeY}}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question you want to disable unchecked checkbox when the total price is equal to 0.

Why do you don't used a model to get the status of the checkbox (checked or unchecked) and test something like :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="yourCtrl.checked[your_checkbox_number]" ng-disable="(yourCtrl.totalPrice <= 0 && !yourCtrl.checked[your_checkbox_number])/>
```

Comment: It works but it disable all the checkbox even the checked ones, I need a solution to disable only the unchecked ones if you have one please suggest it

Comment: yes you will need to have one variable by checkbox in your ng-model.
one way is to used an array and set the model to the index in the array that match to your checkbox number ng-model="yourCtrl.checked[your_checkbox_number]" ng-disable="(yourCtrl.totalPrice <= 0 && !yourCtrl.checked[your_checkbox_number])

Comment: It Worked Thakns Jerely :
<input class="mes_avoires_checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="check" ng-change="avoirPrixCal($index,check,a)"
                                   id="chBx-{{$index}}" ng-disabled="(Topay <= 0 && !check)" />